# How to calculate the angle of lines drawn in flutter? Need to find the angle between two lines

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, gesturedetector, custom-painter

I'm working on a paint like application where lines and shapes can be drawn using tapped coordinates. I need to get the angle or degree of the lines drawn in my canvas. Have used CustomPaint to draw the lines and XGestureDetector to get the coordinates onTap.

[image]

I Need to achieve the above.

Here's my code,

```js
class LandingScreen extends State<MyApp> {
  LandingScreen(List<List<Offset>> connectionList);

  @override
  void initState() {
    XGesture();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    late List<List<Offset>> _connectionList;
    _connectionList = [[Offset(104.0, 242.6), Offset(101.4, 559.3)], [Offset(238.9, 238.6), Offset(229.8, 440.4)]];

    String dropdownvalue = 'Square';
    var items = ['Square', ' Circle ', ' Rectangle ', ' Circle ',];

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body:
        XGesture(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class XGesture extends StatefulWidget {
  late List<List<Offset>> connectionListRedo = [];

  @override
  _XGestureState createState() => _XGestureState();
}

class _XGestureState extends State<XGesture> {
  late MoveEvent pos1;
  late MoveEvent pos2;
  late List<List<Offset>> _connectionList;
  late List<List<Offset>> connectionListRedo1;

  _XGestureState();

  @override
  void initState() {
    onMoveStart;
    pos1 = MoveEvent(Offset(0.0, 0.0), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0);
    pos2 = MoveEvent(Offset(0.0, 0.0), Offset(0.0, 0.0), 0);
    _connectionList = [];
    onMoveEnd;
    LandingScreen(_connectionList);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String dropdownvalue = 'Square';
    var items = [
      'Square',
      ' Circle ',
      ' Rectangle ',
      ' Circle ',
    ];
    String dropdownvalue1 = 'Teams';
    var items1 = [
      'Teams',
      ' Sluggers ',
      ' Lakes ',
      ' Add More ',
    ];

    final x = Angle.degrees(180.0);
    debugPrint('Angle of x : ${x.degrees}');

    return XGestureDetector(
      child: Material(
        color: Colors.black87,
        child: Center(
            child: CustomPaint(
          painter: LinePainter(pos1.localPos, pos2.localPos, _connectionList),
          child:SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child:
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.5,bottom: 0.5,left: 0.0,right: 0.0),
                  decoration:BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4),
                    color: Color(0xDC063280),
                  ),
                  child: TextButton.icon(
                      label: const Text('Undo', textAlign: TextAlign.justify, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),
                      icon: Icon(Icons.undo, color: Colors.white,),
                      onPressed: () {
                        widget.connectionListRedo.add(_connectionList.last);
                        debugPrint('Not Removed Offset List value: ${widget.connectionListRedo}');
                        _connectionList.removeLast();
                        debugPrint('Removed Offset List value: $_connectionList');
                        print('Pressed Undo btn');
                      }),
                ),
        ),
                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child:
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.5,bottom: 0.5,left: 0.0,right: 0.0),
                    decoration:BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4),
                        color: Color(0xDC063280),
                    ),
                    child: TextButton.icon(
                        label: const Text('Redo', textAlign: TextAlign.justify, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.redo, color: Colors.white,),
                        onPressed: () {
                          debugPrint('Not Removed Offset List value in Redo: ${widget.connectionListRedo}');
                          _connectionList.add(widget.connectionListRedo.last);
                          widget.connectionListRedo.removeLast();
                          debugPrint('Retrieved Offset value Redo: $_connectionList');
                          print('Pressed Undo btn');
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child:
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.5,bottom: 0.5,left: 0.0,right: 0.0),
                      decoration:BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4),
                        color: Color(0xDC063280),
                      ),
                      child:
                      TextButton.icon(
                          label: const Text('Line', textAlign: TextAlign.justify, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.create, color: Colors.white),
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('Pressed Line btn');
                          })
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child:
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.5,bottom: 0.5,left: 3.5,right: 0.0),
                      decoration:BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4),
                        color: Color(0xDC063280),
                      ),
                      child:
                      DropdownButton(
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white, size: 30,),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20,
                        ),
                        value: dropdownvalue,
                        dropdownColor: Colors.redAccent,
                        items: items.map((String items) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(items),
                        value: items,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String? value){
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownvalue = value!;
                        });
                        },
                      ),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child:
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.5,bottom: 0.5,left: 0.0,right: 0.0),
                    decoration:BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4),
                      color: Color(0xDC063280),
                    ),
                    child: TextButton.icon(
                        label: const Text('My Videos', textAlign: TextAlign.justify, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),
                        icon: Icon(Icons.image, color: Colors.white,),
                        onPressed: () {
                          print('Pressed Video btn');
                        }),
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child:
                  Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.5,bottom: 0.5,left: 0.0,right: 0.0),
                      decoration:BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4),
                        color: Color(0xDC063280),

                      ),
                      child:
                      TextButton.icon(
                          label: const Text('Notifications', textAlign: TextAlign.justify, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white),),
                          // icon: Icon(Icons.align_vertical_center_sharp, color: Colors.white),
                          icon: Icon(Icons.notifications, color: Colors.white),

                          onPressed: () {
                            print('Pressed Notifications btn');
                          })
                  ),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
                  child:
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.5,bottom: 0.5,left: 3.5,right: 0.0),
                    decoration:BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius:BorderRadius.circular(5),
                        border: Border.all(color: Colors.redAccent, width: 4),
                        color:Colors.black87
                    ),
                    child:
                    DropdownButton(
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, color: Colors.white, size: 30,),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 20,
                      ),
                      value: dropdownvalue1,
                      dropdownColor: Colors.redAccent,
                      items: items1.map((String items) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(items),
                          value: items,
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                      onChanged: (String? value){
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownvalue1 = value!;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
          ),
        )),
      ),
      doubleTapTimeConsider: 300,
      longPressTimeConsider: 350,
      onTap: onTap,
      onMoveStart: onMoveStart,
      onMoveEnd: onMoveEnd,
      onMoveUpdate: onMoveUpdate,
      onScaleStart: onScaleStart,
      onScaleUpdate: onScaleUpdate,
      onScaleEnd: onScaleEnd,
      bypassTapEventOnDoubleTap: false,
    );

  }

  void onScaleEnd() {
    setLastEventName('onScaleEnd');
    print('onScaleEnd');
  }

  void onScaleStart(initialFocusPoint) {
    setLastEventName('onScaleStart');
    print('onScaleStart - initialFocusPoint: ' + initialFocusPoint.toString());
  }

  void onLongPress(pointer, localPos, position) {
    setLastEventName('onLongPress');
    print('onLongPress - pos: ' + localPos.toString());
  }

  void onDoubleTap(localPos, position) {
    setLastEventName('onDoubleTap');
    print('onDoubleTap - pos: ' + localPos.toString());

    _connectionList.removeLast();
  }

  void onTap(event) {
    setLastEventName('onTap');
    print('onTap - pos: ' + event.localPos.toString());
  }

  Future<void> onMoveUpdate(MoveEvent event) async {
    setLastEventName('onMoveUpdate');
    print('onMoveUpdate - pos: ${event.localPos} delta: ${event.delta}');
  }

  void onMoveStart(localPos) {
    setLastEventName('onMoveStart');
    print('onMoveStart - pos: $localPos');
    pos1 = localPos;
    debugPrint('pos1 Local pos: ${pos1.localPos}');
    debugPrint('pos1 delta pos: ${pos1.delta}');
  }

  void onMoveEnd(localPos) {
    setLastEventName('onMoveEnd');
    print('onMoveEnd - pos: $localPos');
    pos2 = localPos;
    debugPrint('pos2 Local pos: ${pos2.localPos}');
    debugPrint('position1 ${pos1.localPos}, position2 ${pos2.localPos}');

    List<Offset> _offsets = [];
    _offsets.add(pos1.localPos);
    _offsets.add(pos2.localPos);
    _connectionList.add(_offsets);

    widget.connectionListRedo = [];

    debugPrint('Offset List value: ${_offsets}, List: $_connectionList');
    LinePainter(pos1.localPos, pos2.localPos, _connectionList);
  }

  void onScaleUpdate(ScaleEvent event) {
    setLastEventName('onScaleUpdate');
    print(
        'onScaleUpdate - changedFocusPoint:  ${event.focalPoint} ; scale: ${event.scale} ;Rotation: ${event.rotationAngle}');
  }
}
```

Since I'm new to Flutter, there'll be some unwanted code. Please ignore those.

Comment: see `Offset.direction`, the official docs say: *"The angle of this offset as radians clockwise from the positive x-axis, in the range -pi to pi, assuming positive values of the x-axis go to the right and positive values of the y-axis go down."*

Comment: @pskink I tried to follow the official documentation but couldn't understand it. Can you please elaborate on this concept and how I can implement this in my code. Thanks in advance

Comment: most likely you think that it is represented as degrees - this is not true: `Offset.direction` is represented as [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) - for conversions between degrees / radians see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian#Conversions)

Comment: @pskink so I need to use (radians * 180)/PI to get the degrees. Now I get it. Thanks